# Using EnvironmentObject and Binding in same struct? [Beginner]

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have managed to set up a Navigationstack that I use programatically to insert/remove views. In my FindOrderView, I want to carry over the variable "ordernumber" to my LoadingScreen(View) using Binding, but I get an error saying my LoadingScreen does not conform to type 'Equatable'. What could I be doing wrong, and is there any other efficient way to get this working?

I'm a complete beginner with SwiftUi but have searched for hours before posting this here. Thankful for any help.

**NavigationRouter (Class used to control layers of views)**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

enum Route: Hashable {
    case ContentView
    case View1
}


final class NavigationRouter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var navigationPath = NavigationPath()
    
    func pushView(route: Route) {
        navigationPath.append(route)
    }
    
    func popToRootView() {
        navigationPath = .init()
    }
    
    func popToSpecificView(k: Int) {
        navigationPath.removeLast(k)
        
    }

}
```

**Mainapp (App starts here but instantly jumps to MainScreenView())**

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct AvhamtningApp: App {
    
    @StateObject var router = NavigationRouter()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack(path: $router.navigationPath) {
                MainScreenView()
                    .navigationDestination(for: Route.self) { route in
                        switch route {
                        case .ContentView:
                            MainScreenView()
                        case .View1:
                            FindOrderView()
                        }
                    }
            }.environmentObject(router)
        }
    }
}
```

**MainScreenView (View with button called "Get order" that carries you over to View1 (FindOrderView))**

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainScreenView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var router: NavigationRouter
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack() {
                Text("Testing")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    .padding(.top, 50)
                
                Spacer()
                PrimaryButton(text: "Get Order")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        router.pushView(route: .View1)
                    }
                Spacer()
                
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color(.white)).ignoresSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct MainScreenView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainScreenView()
    }
}
```

**FindOrderView (View with Keypad, if enter 7 digits then should carry you over to Loadingscreen() with the variable "ordernumber" as binding)**

```
import SwiftUI

var list = [["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"],["7","8","9"],["","0","⌫"]]

struct FindOrderView: View {
    @State private var ordernumber: String = ""
    @EnvironmentObject var router: NavigationRouter
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 25) {
            Text(ordernumber)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .onChange(of: ordernumber) { newValue in
                    if ordernumber.count >= 7 {
                        router.navigationPath.append(LoadingScreen(ordernumber: $ordernumber))
                    }
                }
            Spacer()
            ForEach(list.indices, id: \.self) { listindex in
                
                HStack{
                    ForEach(list[listindex], id: \.self) { variableindex in
                        Text(variableindex)
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .font(.system(size: 60))
                            .onTapGesture(perform: {
                                if variableindex == "⌫" && !ordernumber.isEmpty {
                                    ordernumber.removeLast()
                                }
                                else if ordernumber.count >= 7 {return}
                                
                                else if variableindex == "⌫" {
                                    ()
                                }
                                else {
                                    ordernumber += variableindex
                                }})
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    }
                    
                    }
                }
            
            }.background(.white)
        
        }
    
    }


struct FindOrderView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FindOrderView()
    }
}
```

**LoadingScreen (This is where I get the error "Type 'LoadingScreen' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'")**

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoadingScreen: Hashable, View {
    
    
    @EnvironmentObject var router: NavigationRouter
    @Binding var ordernumber: String
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Text("Loading...")
                .font(Font.custom("Baskerville-Bold", size: 50))
                .foregroundColor(.orange)
                .padding(.bottom, 200)
            
            ProgressView()
                .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .orange))
                .scaleEffect(2)
            

        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color(.white)).ignoresSafeArea(.all)
    }
}


struct LoadingScreen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoadingScreen(ordernumber: .constant("constant"))
    }
}
```

Comment: `Hashable` derives from `Equatable`. Why did you think `LoadingScreen` could be `Hashable`?

Comment: @Jessy Hey Jessy, thanks for commenting. Okay! I only added Hashable to the Loadingscreen view because xcode said it had to conform to it, and then another error popped up saying it had to conform to Equatable. What would you suggest I read up on to more understand what I could be doing wrong? Thank you for your input, appreciated.

Comment: You are being asked to make `LoadingScreen` hashable as in your router you are appending it top the `navigationPath` property.

Comment: @flanker hey! Yes, i thought so aswell, but unable to make it hashable, it seems the Environmentobject and Bindingobject proporties are causing some issues, do you know how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not understanding your approach to navigation logic, and don't have time to work through all the code, so afraid can't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the app starts on the `MainScreenView` because it's set as the root of the NavigationStack.

Your issue with navigation is that you're trying to send the ***view*** as a navigation destination value, but you need to send the ***route*** value, and switch on the `navigationDestination` to generate the view to be pushed.

So in your `Route` enum, add a route for loading:

```swift
case loading(orderNumber: String)
```

Then in your `NavigationLink` send that new route:

```swift
NavigationLink(value: Route.loadingScreen(orderNumber: orderNumber)
```

Then in your `navigationDestination` view modifier:

```swift
.navigationDestination(for: Route.self) { route in
    switch route {
        case .ContentView:
            MainScreenView()
        case .View1:
            FindOrderView()
        case .loading(let orderNumber):
            LoadingScreen(orderNumber: orderNumber)
                .environmentObject(router)
        }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: what if I need to to pass a `.environmentObject(someObj)` to `FindOrderView` and this Obj is declared as `@StateObject private var someObj = SomeObj()` in `MainScreenView`, how to do it in the `navigationDestination` closure ?

Comment: Put it right on your `NavigationStack`, it will propagate the `.environmentObject` to all the child views

Comment: this is not doable, because the object I'm tying to pass is declared inside MainScreenView and the NavigationStack is at the app level.

Comment: It is if you refactor some things :)

Comment: SwiftUI's `EnvironmentValues` is based on the view's scope in code. Since the `MainScreenView and the `FindOrderView` are siblings (next to each other in the same scope) they need to host their shared memory on a parent object somewhere. `NavigationStack` can conveniently encompass and propagate these objects for you if you put `.environmentObject(someObj)` on it. Don't get me wrong there are other ways to accomplish sibling transfer, like a persistent layer, but that's another convo.